# pandas series str.isdigit() function returns NaN for numeric values

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a dataframe. It has a column of type "object". I want to find whether this column contains any numeric values.

So I am using `str.isdigit()` function. The function returns a correct value as "False" for non-numeric data. But if the value is numeric, it returns "NaN". I expected a "True" value instead, in this case.
Can anyone please let me know is it the right way to check for the numeric values? And why it returns NaN instead of True?

**Please find the code below:**

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3],"B":[5,"Six","Seven"]})
d.B.str.isdigit()
```

**Output is:**

```
0      NaN
1    False
2    False
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Comment: `str` is used for string/object values. Your first value is `int` not `str`. You can do `d.B.astype(str).str.isdigit()`